# Aorist active participles in Jn 6:45

Tags: john

In John 6:45 the two aorist active participles ὁ ἀκούσας… καὶ μαθὼν  are translated “has heard and learned (NKJV).” What would the difference in meaning be if they were aorist passive participles? Is there a difference between an active,i.e. engaged hearer and learner, one who is interested and learning from the teaching vs the passive, possibly not engaged, only hearing the words but not listening and not learning? Would the passive participle indicate that meaning?

Comment: _Take heed therefore **how ye hear**: for whosoever hath, to him shall be given; and whosoever hath not, from him shall be taken even that which he seemeth to have._ Luke 8:18. Up-voted +1. Your concept is not present in John 6:45 but it _is present_ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You understand the words “active” and “passive” in the context of *participation*:

[image]

[image]

But, “active” and “passive” as grammatical terms, which is how the words are actually used (i.e., active voice; passive voice), have no bearing on the *degree* of participation of the verbs’ subjects.

[image]

[image]

Consider the following examples:

| Voice | Example |
| --- | --- |
| Active | The audience heard the speaker. |
| Passive | The speaker was heard by the audience. |

In both examples, a speaker is speaking to the audience, and the audience hears the speaker speak. Neither example conveys the degree to which the audience hears. Is the audience fully engaged with every word the speaker speaks? Are some of the audience falling alseep? The active and passive voice simply do not convey such information, whether in English or in Greek.

---

In John 6:45, the Greek phrase,

> ...πᾶς οὖν ὁ ἀκούσας παρὰ τοῦ πατρὸς καὶ μαθὼν ἔρχεται πρὸς με.

is often translated into English as,

> Therefore, everyone who has heard and learned **of** the Father...

The idea this translation conveys is of someone who hears and learns **of** or **about** God. However, this is **not** what the Greek text is expressing.

When the preposition παρὰ follows the verbs ἀκούω, “hear”,
the **object of the preposition παρὰ is the speaker**.

Hence, Thayer,<sup>1</sup>

> b. to get by hearing, learn (from the mouth of the teacher or narrator): Acts 15:17; Mt. 10:27 (ὃ εἰς τὸ οὖς ἀκούετε, what is taught you in secret); Ro. 15:21; Eph. 1:13; Col. 1:6; Jn. 14:24; 1 Jn. 2:7, 24; 3:11; Χριστόν i. e. to become acquainted with Christ from apostolic teaching, Eph. 4:21 (cf. μαθεῖν τὸν Χριστόν, vs. 20 [B. 166 (144) note; W. 199 (187) note]); pass., Lk. 12:3; Heb. 2:1; **τὶ with gen. of pers. fr. whom one hears**, Acts 1:4; **τὶ παρά τινος, Jn. 8:26, 40; 15:15**; Acts 10:22; 28:22; 2 Tim. 2:2, (Thuc. 6, 93; Xen. an. 1, 2, 5 [here Dind. om. παρά]; Plat. rep. vi. p. 506 d., al.; [B. 166 (145); W. 199 (188)]); [**παρά τινος, without an obj. expressed, Jn. 1:40** (41)]; ἔκ τινος, Jn. 12:34 (ἐκ τοῦ νόμου, from attendance on its public reading); ἀπό with gen. of pers., 1 Jn. 1:5; with περί τινος added, Acts 9:13; foll. by ὅτι, Mt. 5:21, 27, 33, 38, 43.

John 1:40

> One of the two who **heard John**...
> εἷς ἐκ τῶν δύο τῶν ἀκουσάντων **παρὰ Ἰωάννου**...

John 7:51

> Does our Law judge a man unless it **hears him** before...
> Μὴ ὁ νόμος ἡμῶν κρίνει τὸν ἄνθρωπον ἐὰν μὴ **ἀκούσῃ παρ᾽ αὐτοῦ** πρότερον...

John 8:26

> ...and I speak to the world those things which **I have heard from Him**.
> ...κἀγὼ ἃ **ἤκουσα παρ᾽ αὐτοῦ** ταῦτα λὲγω εἰς τὸν κόσμον

John 8:40

> But now you seek to kill me, a man that has told you the truth, which **I have heard from God**...
> νῦν δὲ ζητεῖτέ με ἀποκτεῖναι ἄνθρωπον ὃς τὴν ἀλήθειαν ὑμῖν λελάληκα ἣν **ἤκουσα παρὰ τοῦ θεοῦ**

John 15:15

> ...since everything that **I have heard from my Father**, I have made known to you.
> ...ὅτι πάντα ἃ **ἤκουσα παρὰ τοῦ πατρός μου** ἐγνώρισα ὑμῖν.

John 6:45 should be translated and understood as follows,

> Therefore, everyone who has heard and learned **from** the Father...

The teacher is the Father. The «διδακτοὶ τοῦ θεοῦ» are those taught **by** God. Everyone who has heard and learned from the Father comes to Jesus. But, then you say, “Well, the Father wasn’t teaching. Jesus was.” And to that I say: both the Father and the Son were teaching. The Father was teaching through His Son. Jesus himself said, “Everything that **I have heard from my Father**, I have made known to you”. Jesus spoke what the Father commanded him to speak.<sup>3</sup>

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Thayer, p. [23](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false) <sup>2</sup> John 6:45 <sup>3</sup> John 12:49–50 |

| References |
| --- |
| Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889. |

Comment: Does not the grammar reflect the act of participation or its lack ?

Comment: @NigelJ—Yes. If a person is not the subject of the verb, then naturally he is not a participant in the verb’s action. I edited my answer to “degree of participation”. In other words, a verb being active voice or passive voice does nothing to relate to the reader the degree of the subject’s participation in the activity, viz., the OP’s “engaged hearer and learner... vs[.] passive, possibly not engaged”.

For example, “He

Answer (score -1):

The grammar of active and passive is:

If you change the active participle, ἀκούσας, "Everyone who has heard and learned from the Father," to passive, the meaning would change to, "Everyone who has been heard and learned from by the Father." This would be a drastically different meaning, in that rather than the passive would make the Father doing the hearing.  The participle μαθὼν would be difficult to make sense of a passive.

Active: to teach

Passive: to be taught by

Active: to learn (similar to passive of to be taught by)

Passive: to be learned by (the subject typically is not a person, eg. Hebrew and Greek are being learned by the student)

Note how active and passive changes the meaning.

Thus, in this passage to switch from passive to active with the similar meaning, it has "be taught by God" and "learn." However, here, while the English translation is passive, διδακτοὶ is an adjective and ἔσονται is future middle.  Thus, to switch from active to passive the verb had to change to a different verb.

Comment: Changing the preposition only makes an alteration in the _type_ of agency.

Comment: @DerÜbermensch - "was heard" can be passive as per Matt 2:18.

Comment: I edited this answer with the help of Mary.  I needed some sleep when I answered this before.

Comment: Could the meaning of heard instead be “to be spoken to” and learn could be “taught” so in the passive “everyone who has been spoken to and taught” or would that be incorrect?

Comment: Could the passive there indicate the people are being spoken to by the father rather than the father being the hearer, that he’s the one speaking but the hearer is the one spoken to?